# Why does the executable version of my Python program doesn't execute os.listdir and os.path.isdir correctly? OS is Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, debugging, operating-system, pyinstaller

I have this program that prints a dictionary which has **folder names** as keys and **filenames** as values for a given `path`:

```
import os
if os.name == 'nt': # Let's add some colors for the lulz
    from ctypes import windll
    k = windll.kernel32
    k.SetConsoleMode(k.GetStdHandle(-11), 7)

# Main method
the_dictionary_list = {}
print('\u001b[43mHi Sailor! I am "SAND-wich", a simple program built by @NoahVerner\033[0m')
print('\n')
time.sleep(2)
def check_path(infile):
    return os.path.exists(infile)    
        
first_entry = input('Tell me the path in which your folders with images are located:')

while True:
    
    if check_path(first_entry) == False:
        print('\n')
        print('This PATH is invalid!')
        first_entry = input('Tell me the RIGHT PATH in which your folders with ONLY images are located:')
        
    elif check_path(first_entry) == True:
        print('\n')
        final_output = first_entry
        break

print('This PATH has the following folders with the following files:')
print('\n')
for name in os.listdir(first_entry):
    if os.path.isdir(name):
        path = os.path.basename(name)
        print(f'\u001b[45m{path}\033[0m')
        list_of_file_contents = os.listdir(path)
        print(f'\033[46m{list_of_file_contents}')
        the_dictionary_list[path] = list_of_file_contents
print('\n')
print('\u001b[43mthe_dictionary_list:\033[0m')
print(the_dictionary_list)
print('\n')
```

Within a `.py` file, the code above works as expected without any errors.

[image: Spyder output]

After exporting this program as a single executable file using the following sentence on `cmd`:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=./SAND-wich_icon.ico SAND-wich.py
```

I get these folders:

[image: folders]

From which the `dist` folder contains the `.exe` file that I want.

[image: .exe file]

So I run `SAND-wich.exe` as `Admin` **not without first having my** `AVG Antivirus` **deactivated** (because it doesn't let that program run correctly neither)

And that executable file **DOES RECOGNIZE that the** `path` **I'm passing as input IS INDEED A PATH**.

However, **IT DOES NOT return the desired dictionary with the expected values**, **it returns an empty one**:

[image: empty dictionary]

What's causing this problem? Assume that the `path` I'm passing in both scenarios is the same one and only contain folders which only contain `png` images, and the `os` in which the executable file will run is `Windows 10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was something dumb in the `.py` code actually

```
for name in os.listdir(first_entry):
    backslash = "\\"
    if os.path.isdir(first_entry+backslash+name):
        path = os.path.basename(name)
        print(f'\u001b[45m{path}\033[0m')
        list_of_file_contents = os.listdir(first_entry+backslash+path)
        print(f'\033[46m{list_of_file_contents}')
        the_dictionary_list[path] = list_of_file_contents
print('\n')
print('\u001b[43mthe_dictionary_list:\033[0m')
print(the_dictionary_list)
print('\n')
```

Comparison made on [Diffchecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/), previous version vs new one.
[image: solved]